# Using JavaScript variables in XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, twilio, fs

Is there anyway to use JavaScript variables in an XML file that is hosted online? I want to customize the XML content passed on the URL.

for example, if I have a file located at

**www.mywebsite.com/file.xml?NAME=JOE**

here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
//XML FILE
    <Response>
    <Say voice="alice">
            Hey Im this is a great xml file {{NAME}}
    </Say>
    </Response>
```

if so, how?

Comment: You would need to use some server-side code (Node.js, ASP.NET, PHP, etc.) to receive the request, generate the XML, and return it. XML all by itself can't do what you're describing.

Comment: @JLRishe, how would i do this with nodejs? I have the code written, simply writing the file but Im unable to host on heroku or anywhere - since it has to be raw XML file, i cant store it in S3, etc

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to customise content in an XML file, you need to generate the XML from a server side language of some sort. Since you would like to use JavaScript, then Node.js is probably your best bet.

Your comment says that the file has to be a raw XML file, but I see you are responding to an [incoming phone call with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request). You can absolutely generate on the fly XML responses with Node.js to respond to [Twilio webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml).

Here's a very quick example of a Node.js server, using the [express framework](http://expressjs.com/), that would respond with the name in the way you suggest in the question (note that Twilio doesn't pass a Name query parameter when it makes [webhook requests](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request)). It uses the [Twilio Node.js helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) to generate the XML on the fly:

```
var express = require('express');
var twilio = require('twilio');

var app = new express();

app.post('/voice', function(request, response) {
  var name = request.query.Name;
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  twiml.say('Hey! This is a great x m l file ' + name);

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
})

app.listen(3000);
```

You would need to host this somewhere that can run Node.js applications.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thanks phil but I need to create the XML file for it to live on my site for a few hours. heroku doesnt allow for that.. this was my last resort to have a static 'template' twiml and just try pass the variables..

any suggestions @phil?

Comment: Why do you need to create and host the XML? I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: because they are user generated, have custom var and have to be accessible in the future @phil

Comment: and these are creating calls, so from my understanding, twilio needs to be able to POST in order to `client.createCAll`

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Could you not save the details the user generates in a database and then generate the XML from them using Node every time?